# Rails polymorphic form for message system - user <-> admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used [this](https://medium.com/@batuhanwilhelm/rails-5-messaging-system-no-gem-b4a52bc4ebb4) guide as a starting point for creating a messaging system from scratch. The idea is to have conversations between `User` and `AdminUser`. I want the `AdminUser` respond to questions sent it by `User`. `AdminUser` can have many conversations with the same `User` (there can be several topics of conversation, each topic is a separate conversation).

The Admin should be able to see the previous conversations with a reply box.

Like in the article I've created below db structure:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations, as: :sendable
  has_many :conversations, as: :recipientable
end


class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :conversations, as: :sendable
  has_many :conversations, as: :recipientable
end

class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sendable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :recipientable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  validates :sendable_id, uniqueness: { scope: :recipientable_id }
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true

  validates_presence_of :body
end
```

Inside the article provided earlier I read that:

> We also added “messageable” as polymorphic. This way, both Admin and User can send messages to conversation with their respective references.

What "messageable" is responsible for? because to create new message I need to provide this messageble_id and I don't now what it is.

```
# app/views/messages/index.html.erb

<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <%= message.body %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@conversation, @message] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :body %>
 <%= f.submit "Send Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :fetch_conversation

  def index
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def new
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end

  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation) if @message.save
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :messageable_id)
  end

  def fetch_conversation
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end
end
```

With above code I've got an error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Messageable must exist

Which means I need to provide `messageable_id` and probably `messageable_type` but what are these values?

Comment: I think your current structure is missing stuff on Message; how do you know who sent the message? You only know who started a conversation with who, but the messages themselves seem to not be connected to anything. You usually need to know who said what in a chat system

Comment: Hm in such case I think I should store as `messageable_id = user.id` and `messageable_type = 'User'`. So in the view I can search `<% user = User.find(message.messageable_id) %>` and then `<%= user.name %>`. But it's probably not very readable or am I wrong?

Comment: It can work. So your messagable will be the user who sent the message (the sender), and I guess you can write logic to get the message's recipient through the conversation model.  You can also simply add sender_id / recipient_id to message itself if this gets cumbersome

Comment: The question is do I really need those `messageable_id` and `messageable_type` and whole polymorpic  association - `belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true` ?is not a simpler to replace it by `sender_id` and `recipient_id` like you wrote?